# panel height with dynamically added divs in jquery

Tags: jquery

we have a asp.net panel to which we are assigning jqplots from jquery.

we have to get the total panel height with all its child divs, 
after the plotting is done.

can somebody advise how to get that in jquery?

basically I want the panel height, which has dynamically added divs (inside divs jqplots exists)

html:

```
<div id="pnlEmail" style="height:3000px">
   <div style="height: 2080px;"> </div>
   <div style="height: 1000px;"> </div>
   <div style="height: 80px;"> </div>
   <div style="height: 180px;"> </div>
   <div style="height: 2080px;"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59wnW/10/)

HTML

```
height: <span id="height"></span>

<div id="pnlEmail">
   <div style="height: 2080px;"> </div>
   <div style="height: 1000px;"> </div>
   <div style="height: 80px;"> </div>
   <div style="height: 180px;"> </div>
   <div style="height: 2080px;"> </div>
</div>
```

use height function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var child = $('#pnlEmail').children();
    var h=0.0;
    $(child).each(function(){
        h+=parseFloat($(this).height());
    });
$('#height').html(h);

});
```

Comment: this gives just panel height, it does not includes it childs heights

Comment: please post your html.

Comment: unable to post the entire html, but updated a sample in question. pls see

Comment: answers has been modified.

Comment: try above and let me know.